# Unsupported operation :not writeable python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Email validation

```
#Email validator
import re


def is_email():
    email=input("Enter your email")
    pattern = '[\.\w]{1,}[@]\w+[.]\w+'
    file = open('ValidEmails.txt','r')
    if re.match(pattern, email):
        file.write(email)
```

I am wondering why my data wont write to the disk. Python says that my operation is not supported.

```
is_email
    file.write(email)
io.UnsupportedOperation: not writable
```

Answer (score 138, accepted):

You open the variable "file" as a read only then attempt to write to it:

```
file = open('ValidEmails.txt','r')
```

Instead, use the 'w' flag.

```
file = open('ValidEmails.txt','w')
...
file.write(email)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
file = open('ValidEmails.txt','wb')
file.write(email.encode('utf-8', 'ignore'))
```

This is solve your `encode error` also.

Answer (score 0):

use this :

```
#Email validator
import re


def is_email():
    email=input("Enter your email")
    pattern = '[\.\w]{1,}[@]\w+[.]\w+'
    file = open('ValidEmails.txt','w')
    if re.match(pattern, email):
        file.write(email)
```