# Saving user inputs so that they appear again - python 3.2

Tags: python, user-input, saving-data

I am trying to get my user input to save however, when i have tried doing so, this message comes up in the python shell:

```
 nf.write('\n'.join(tempword))
io.UnsupportedOperation: not writable
```

Here is my code for that section:

```
 clues_list=[]
    userInput=input("Enter a symbol you would like to replace:")
    userInput2=input("What letter would you like to replace it with:")

    for word in words_list:
        tempword = (word)
        tempword = tempword.replace('#','A')
        tempword = tempword.replace('*', 'M')
        tempword = tempword.replace('%', 'N')
        tempword=tempword.replace(userInput,userInput2)
        print(tempword)
        clues_list.append(tempword)
        with open('words.txt', 'r') as nf:# bit that isnt working 
            nf.write('\n'.join(tempword))
```

Basically, i want the user input to be displayed however that isnt happening. Can someone please explain to me why and what i need to do to fix it ?
Regards

Comment: exact dupe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27278755/unsupported-operation-not-writeable-python

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you're opening `words.txt` as read only, then trying to write to it. Try instead:

```
with open('words.txt', 'w') as nf:
    nf.write('\n'.join(tempword))
```

Note that this will blank your file before writing to it. If you need to append to the end of your file, use the `'a'` (`'append'`) mode instead.

Comment: thank you however i just tried it with the 'a' for append and now all of a sudden a whole list of differnt symbols and letters show up one by one on the interpreter. I took out the append again however it still keeps happening

Comment: @0123456 `file_obj.write` returns the number of characters in the string that was written [as per the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html?highlight=file%20object#methods-of-file-objects). You can safely ignore those since you're running in the interpreter, or just assign them to an unused variable (e.g. `_ = nf.write("\n".join(tempword))`)

Comment: @0123456 note that this is the same thing that makes `2+2` show you `4` in the interpreter, but running that same code from the console shows you no output.