# with open multiple files without overriding each previous file created (python)

Tags: python

I have a game and I would like to save game data after each time it is played. I am trying to use `with open` to create new files named *todaysdate*.csv (the game will not be played more than once per day). Below is the code I have:

```
get_date = datetime.today().strftime('%Y%m%d')

with open("[].csv".format(get_date)) as text_file:
    # text_file.write(game_data)
    print(game_data, file=text_file)
    text_file.close()
```

I get this error:

```
print(game_data, file=text_file)
io.UnsupportedOperation: not writable
```

Previously, I simply had:

```
with open("testing.csv") as text_file:
    # text_file.write(game_data)
    print(game_data, file=text_file)
    text_file.close()
```

And this worked just fine, other than it would override the file every time the game was played. Any ideas about how to fix this? It would also be great if I could specify the folder these files all go into, but I have not gotten that far yet.

Comment: Please take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27278755/unsupported-operation-not-writeable-python. This might answer your question

Comment: @Lexpj Please flag the question as duplicate instead of suggesting a link in a comment. This will help others to mark the question as duplicate

Comment: By the way, it should be `"{}.csv".format(get_date)`

Comment: There were two problems. @Lexpj that thread answers the "open in write mode" problem, but not the "don't overwrite the file" problem. Not sure whether that qualifies the question as a duplicate or not, though.

Comment: @tehCheat How is it ***not*** a duplicate? It takes exactly two seconds to copy-paste the error to Google and the first result is the duplicate...

Comment: Regarding the second problem this is just a typo - it should be `{}.csv` instead of `[].csv`

Comment: You're right Tomerikoo, will do!

Comment: lol relax, I am just trying to understand and be helpful. the title of the question includes "without overwriting", so yes, that is clearly a problem.

Comment: @tehCheat I'm super relaxed. There is just no point in answering obvious duplicated questions. This goes against the point of this website. This question is not focused, caused by a typo, and a duplicate - three reasons in the flagging dialog to close it. Please don't answer such questions. Thank you

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts ... I don't see "caused by a typo", and "not focused" seems a bit subjective. So I respectfully disagree. And I also am still not sure the question is a duplicate, though it is clearly partially solved by another post. So, no thank you, I will answer such questions.

Comment: Caused by a typo is under *"A community-specific reason"*. And I don't see how not focused is subjective. You yourself just said there are two problems. The question is all over the place - the title says one thing, the body complains about another error. So again, the question is basically asking two questions, one of which is a typo and the other is a duplicate

Comment: Hi there. Thanks for catching the typo, my bad. Fixing the typo does not solve my file override problem named in the title (and neither does the link provided by Lexpj). The answer provided by tehCheat does solve my problem (with a slight modification because game_data is not already in a valid csv format). Thanks to TehCheat

Comment: @Tomerikoo Zooming out from the trees to the forest: the OP wanted help. I wanted to help. Neither of us wanted any form of gatekeeping. Between using bold and italics, using terms like "no point", "obvious", and "So again", it sure seems like you're not treating others the way you would want to be treated. That feels discouraging to new users, and to anyone who would prefer not to be treated like an idiot. But hey, if you want to nitpick and flag questions, you sure can.

Comment: Let's keep it at that. Glad tehCheat was able to help out.

Comment: I am happy that you were able to get your problem solved, but I just have to understand one thing. You said *"Fixing the typo does not solve my file override problem named in the title (and neither does the link provided by Lexpj). The answer provided by tehCheat does"*. But that answer is telling you to fix the typo and to do exactly what is said in the link...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first argument to `open()` is the file name,  the second is the mode ("read" by default).

Assuming `game_data` is already in valid CSV format, you want:

```
todays_date = datetime.today().strftime('%Y%m%d')

with open(f"{todays_date}.csv", "w") as text_file:
    text_file.write(game_data)
    text_file.close()
```

To not overwrite data, proper use of formatted string (`f"{todays_date}.csv"`) is needed. `{}`, not `[]`.